# Materialized view is not refreshing in Postgres 10.4

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I am importing a table from remotely located database say DB1 using DBlink and creating a materialized view in Postgres (DB2). This is working fine but at the time of refreshing materialized view updated data from source table (DB1) is not reflecting the changes in Postgres materialized view.

Please find the steps below.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS schemaDB2.test_view  
AS 
SELECT * 
FROM dblink('foreign_server','select col1,col2 from schemaDB1.tablename') AS t1 (col1 varchar,col2 varchar);
commit;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS dummyindex ON schemaDB2.test_view (col1);

REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY schemaDB2.test_view WITH DATA;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get the expected result if you run the query? Do you get an error on `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`?

Comment: Sorry for delay response.First two queries are working fine and getting expected result . I am not getting any error while running REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW but also the view is not refreshing.

Comment: It would help to have a reproducible test case.

Comment: Its working now.

Comment: So what was the problem?